# Trend in timeseriesdata

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am using a Keras sequential model with LSTM layers with timeseries data to predict future values. For this I have split my data in training and validation data at a certain point in time. The timeseries data has a positive trend, thus the average values in my training data are lower then in my validation data as I am using the more recent data as validation.

The initial model predicts every time 0.5, which is a bad model. In the next epoch the model will learn by the training data and predict values on average lower than 0.5 which decreases training loss but increases validation loss.
Only after a lot of epochs I will see to start a decreasing behavior for the validation loss and after even more epochs the validation loss will be lower for the first time than the first bad always prediction 0.5 model.

I am using Keras tuner with the Hyperband tuner for hyperparameter validation. This does not work for this timeseries as in its first rounds all models will show higher validation loss then the bad initial 0.5 model.

Is there a way to handle trend in timeseries in combination with Keras and splitting training and validation data? It is not possible for me to shuffle the timeseries and then split the data as I would really like to use the more recent data for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try differencing the function, that way the model would be predicting the change in value for each timestep with respect to the previous timestep:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def difference_column(df, target_col):
    yesterday = df.loc[:,target_col].shift()
    return yesterday.diff()

df = pd.DataFrame(range(1,100), columns = ['target_var']) * 2
df_diff = difference_column(df, 'target_var')

print(df, df_diff)
```

Output:

```
    target_var
0            2
1            4
2            6
3            8
4           10
..         ...
94         190
95         192
96         194
97         196
98         198

[99 rows x 1 columns] 0     NaN
1     NaN
2     2.0
3     2.0
4     2.0
     ... 
94    2.0
95    2.0
96    2.0
97    2.0
98    2.0
Name: target_var, Length: 99, dtype: float64
```

After this initial experiment, head over [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.tools.diff.html)

Comment: This is a good solution. I have combined it with scaling all data on the range of the training data, which was suggested by a friend of mine. The model seems to work now, thank you. Unfortunately I am not allowed yet to upvote posts, so I cannot upvote your answers.

Comment: Excellent suggestion by your friend! :) happy modelling!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this example](http://class%20WindowGenerator():%20%20%20def%20__init__(self,%20input_width,%20label_width,%20shift,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20train_df=train_df,%20val_df=val_df,%20test_df=test_df,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label_columns=None):%20%20%20%20%20#%20Store%20the%20raw%20data.%20%20%20%20%20self.train_df%20=%20train_df%20%20%20%20%20self.val_df%20=%20val_df%20%20%20%20%20self.test_df%20=%20test_df%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20Work%20out%20the%20label%20column%20indices.%20%20%20%20%20self.label_columns%20=%20label_columns%20%20%20%20%20if%20label_columns%20is%20not%20None:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.label_columns_indices%20=%20%7Bname:%20i%20for%20i,%20name%20in%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enumerate(label_columns)%7D%20%20%20%20%20self.column_indices%20=%20%7Bname:%20i%20for%20i,%20name%20in%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enumerate(train_df.columns)%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20Work%20out%20the%20window%20parameters.%20%20%20%20%20self.input_width%20=%20input_width%20%20%20%20%20self.label_width%20=%20label_width%20%20%20%20%20self.shift%20=%20shift%20%20%20%20%20%20self.total_window_size%20=%20input_width%20+%20shift%20%20%20%20%20%20self.input_slice%20=%20slice(0,%20input_width)%20%20%20%20%20self.input_indices%20=%20np.arange(self.total_window_size)%5Bself.input_slice%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20self.label_start%20=%20self.total_window_size%20-%20self.label_width%20%20%20%20%20self.labels_slice%20=%20slice(self.label_start,%20None)%20%20%20%20%20self.label_indices%20=%20np.arange(self.total_window_size)%5Bself.labels_slice%5D%20%20%20%20def%20__repr__(self):%20%20%20%20%20return%20%27%5Cn%27.join(%5B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f%27Total%20window%20size:%20%7Bself.total_window_size%7D%27,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f%27Input%20indices:%20%7Bself.input_indices%7D%27,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f%27Label%20indices:%20%7Bself.label_indices%7D%27,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f%27Label%20column%20name(s):%20%7Bself.label_columns%7D%27%5D)) by `Tensorflow` where they present a class that allows you to easily turn your timeseries into a supervised learning problem (i.e. train & test datasets).

If you look in [that same example](http://class%20WindowGenerator():%20%20%20def%20__init__(self,%20input_width,%20label_width,%20shift,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20train_df=train_df,%20val_df=val_df,%20test_df=test_df,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label_columns=None):%20%20%20%20%20#%20Store%20the%20raw%20data.%20%20%20%20%20self.train_df%20=%20train_df%20%20%20%20%20self.val_df%20=%20val_df%20%20%20%20%20self.test_df%20=%20test_df%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20Work%20out%20the%20label%20column%20indices.%20%20%20%20%20self.label_columns%20=%20label_columns%20%20%20%20%20if%20label_columns%20is%20not%20None:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.label_columns_indices%20=%20%7Bname:%20i%20for%20i,%20name%20in%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enumerate(label_columns)%7D%20%20%20%20%20self.column_indices%20=%20%7Bname:%20i%20for%20i,%20name%20in%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enumerate(train_df.columns)%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20Work%20out%20the%20window%20parameters.%20%20%20%20%20self.input_width%20=%20input_width%20%20%20%20%20self.label_width%20=%20label_width%20%20%20%20%20self.shift%20=%20shift%20%20%20%20%20%20self.total_window_size%20=%20input_width%20+%20shift%20%20%20%20%20%20self.input_slice%20=%20slice(0,%20input_width)%20%20%20%20%20self.input_indices%20=%20np.arange(self.total_window_size)%5Bself.input_slice%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20self.label_start%20=%20self.total_window_size%20-%20self.label_width%20%20%20%20%20self.labels_slice%20=%20slice(self.label_start,%20None)%20%20%20%20%20self.label_indices%20=%20np.arange(self.total_window_size)%5Bself.labels_slice%5D%20%20%20%20def%20__repr__(self):%20%20%20%20%20return%20%27%5Cn%27.join(%5B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f%27Total%20window%20size:%20%7Bself.total_window_size%7D%27,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f%27Input%20indices:%20%7Bself.input_indices%7D%27,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f%27Label%20indices:%20%7Bself.label_indices%7D%27,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f%27Label%20column%20name(s):%20%7Bself.label_columns%7D%27%5D)) you will also find some data transformation steps that should help you get a better model.

Encode your data so the numbers present the relationship found in your input data, i.e. if your column describes wind-direction, encode is such that 360 degrees is exactly as far away from 359 degrees as it is from 0 degrees. They do this by multiplying by wind-speed, and then taking the sin and cos components of these columns. Time-series data preprocessing is a broad topic that you can spend many hours working on.

Another step that might help your model break free from predicting the mean of the training data at every step is normalization: squeezing all values between 0 and 1 and removing the mean from the dataset.

I am not an authority on Keras Sequential models, but here is something to get you started:

This model can at least predict a sin function 30 steps into the future.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout

def make_model(x_train, y_train, print_summary = True):
                    
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(keras.Input(shape = (x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])))
        
        model.add(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences = False))
        model.add(Activation('tanh'))
        
        model.add(Dense(units = 100, activation = 'relu')
        model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.2))
        
        model.add(Dense(units = y_train.shape[1], activation = 'relu')
        
        model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam())
        
        if print_summary: model.summary()
        return model
```

You should experiment with activation functions, adding normalization and dropout.

if i give it this input:

```
sin_df = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range('2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-12-31 
23:00:00', freq = 'H'))
sin_df['data'] = np.float32(np.sin(range(len(sin_df))))
```

and i cut it into samples using this function:

```
def multivariate_data(df, start_index, end_index, history_size, target_size,
                          remove_na = True, target = 0, step = 1, single_step=False):
        
        target = df[:,target]
        data = []
        labels = []
        start_index = start_index + history_size
        
        if end_index is None:
            end_index = len(df) - target_size

        for i in range(start_index, end_index, step):
            indices = range(i-history_size, i)
            data.append(df[indices])

            if single_step:
                labels.append(target[i+target_size])
            else:
                labels.append(target[i:i+target_size])
            
        return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

train_test_split = '2015-06-01'
train_test_index = len(self.df.loc[:train_test_split])-target_size

x_train, y_train = multivariate_data(sin_df.values, 0, train_test_index-1, 100, 30)
x_test, y_test = multivariate_data(sin_df.values, train_test_index+1, None, 100, 30)
```

I can then call fit:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                                        epochs          = 25, 
                                        batch_size      = 24,
                                        validation_data = (x_test, y_test),
                                        callbacks       = [],
                                        verbose         = 2,
                                        shuffle         = False)
```

This is what my output V y_test looks like:

```
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
```

[image: predictions V y_test]

Comment: Thank you for your extremely extensive answer. As this is my first practical project with Keras I might have been a bit vague with my question. To translate the problem I am having to your example is when I would like to predict f=2x, instead of in your example f=sin(x).

Comment: Don't worry about it, writing it down as an answer to your question helps my process aswell, most of the code is copy paste from something I've been working on, you are running into the same problems I was about 12 months ago. Just keep at it, at some point one of your models will give you an output that will have you spring up in excitement and 6 months later you're helping others on stackoverflow.

Upvote my first answer so it is moved on top :)